# При нажатии на кнопку постепенно меняется значение opacity

Tags: javascript, css, opacity

Нужно сделать эффект накаливания лампы. В голову пришло только изменение значения opacity. При нажатии на кнопку opacity с нуля каждую секунду возрастает на 0.05 до 1. При повторном нажатии на кнопку , так же постепенно opacity уменьшается. Включить/выключить лампу. Из кода только css:

```
.led {
    background: url(led.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
    margin: 0;
}
.light {
  background: #FF8C00;
  display: flex;
  opacity: .4;
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  filter: blur(8px);
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Без html-разметки, скриптов и картинки, стили, приведённые Вами, для отвечающих бесполезны. Покажите ваши попытки реализации, прикрепив больше информации.

Answer (score 3):

можете css `transition` использовать если подойдет.

```js
$("button").click(function(){$(this).toggleClass('active');});
```

```css
button {
  opacity:0.25;
  transition: 3s opacity ease;
}
button.active{
  opacity:1;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>button</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.lamp {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

.lamp::before,
.lamp::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: no-repeat center center / contain;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.lamp::before {
  background-image: url('//i.imgur.com/fIzOGIi.png');
  z-index: 2;
}

.lamp::after {
  background-image: url('//i.imgur.com/PXjWQPc.png');
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}

#lamp {
  display: none;
}

#lamp:checked ~ .lamp::after {
  opacity: 1;
}

label[for="lamp"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 3px 0;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#lamp:not(:checked) ~ label[for="lamp"] > span:last-child,
#lamp:checked ~ label[for="lamp"] > span:first-child {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<input id="lamp" type="checkbox">
<div class="lamp"></div>
<label for="lamp"><span>on</span> \ <span>off</span></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю немного *магии* от себя: *реализация на svg + css animation + js*

```js
const lamp = document.querySelector(".lamp");

lamp.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (lamp.classList.contains("lamp-heats-down")) {
    lamp.classList.remove("lamp-heats-down");
    lamp.classList.add("lamp-heats-up");
  } else if (lamp.classList.contains("lamp-heats-up")) {
    lamp.classList.remove("lamp-heats-up");
    lamp.classList.add("lamp-heats-down");
  } else {
    lamp.classList.add("lamp-heats-up");
  }
  
  /* Если нужно чтобы прозрачность менялась каждую секунду измени 5000 на 20000  */
  lamp.style.pointerEvents = "none";
  const lampTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
    lamp.style.pointerEvents = "all";
  }, 5000);
});
```

```css
.lamp-outer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.lamp {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.lamp-heats-down path.lamp-glass-color {
  fill: #ffc107;
  /* Если нужно чтобы прозрачность менялась каждую секунду измени 5s на 1 / 0.05 = 20s   */
  animation: lamp-glass-heats-down 5s ease-out forwards;
}

.lamp-heats-up path.lamp-glass-color {
  fill: #ffc107;
  /* Если нужно чтобы прозрачность менялась каждую секунду измени 5s на 1 / 0.05 = 20s   */
  animation: lamp-glass-heats-up 5s ease-in forwards;
}

@keyframes lamp-glass-heats-up {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes lamp-glass-heats-down {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="lamp-outer">
  <svg class="lamp" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" height="100" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <path class="lamp-glass-color" d="m19 12c0 2.16-.98 4.16-2.67 5.5-.69.54-1.14 1.25-1.28 2.01-.02-.01-.03-.01-.05-.01h-6c-.02 0-.05 0-.07.01-.14-.79-.55-1.48-1.14-1.92-2.18-1.65-3.2-4.35-2.64-7.07.55-2.65 2.7-4.81 5.35-5.36 2.11-.45 4.27.07 5.91 1.4 1.65 1.34 2.59 3.32 2.59 5.44z" fill="transparent"/><path d="m15.05 19.51c-.03.17-.05.34-.05.52v2.22c0 .96-.79 1.75-1.75 1.75h-2.5c-.84 0-1.75-.64-1.75-2.04v-1.77c0-.23-.02-.46-.07-.68.02-.01.05-.01.07-.01h6c.02 0 .03 0 .05.01z" fill="#607d8b"/><path d="m14.25 21h-4.5c-.414 0-.75-.336-.75-.75s.336-.75.75-.75h4.5c.414 0 .75.336.75.75s-.336.75-.75.75z"/><path d="m12 3.457c-.414 0-.75-.336-.75-.75v-1.957c0-.414.336-.75.75-.75s.75.336.75.75v1.957c0 .414-.336.75-.75.75z"/><path d="m18.571 6.179c-.192 0-.384-.073-.53-.22-.293-.293-.293-.768 0-1.061l1.384-1.384c.293-.293.768-.293 1.061 0s.293.768 0 1.061l-1.384 1.384c-.147.146-.339.22-.531.22z"/><path d="m23.25 12.75h-1.957c-.414 0-.75-.336-.75-.75s.336-.75.75-.75h1.957c.414 0 .75.336.75.75s-.336.75-.75.75z"/><path d="m19.955 20.705c-.192 0-.384-.073-.53-.22l-1.384-1.384c-.293-.293-.293-.768 0-1.061s.768-.293 1.061 0l1.384 1.384c.293.293.293.768 0 1.061-.147.147-.339.22-.531.22z"/><path d="m4.045 20.705c-.192 0-.384-.073-.53-.22-.293-.293-.293-.768 0-1.061l1.384-1.384c.293-.293.768-.293 1.061 0s.293.768 0 1.061l-1.384 1.384c-.147.147-.339.22-.531.22z"/><path d="m2.707 12.75h-1.957c-.414 0-.75-.336-.75-.75s.336-.75.75-.75h1.957c.414 0 .75.336.75.75s-.336.75-.75.75z"/><path d="m5.429 6.179c-.192 0-.384-.073-.53-.22l-1.384-1.384c-.293-.293-.293-.768 0-1.061s.768-.293 1.061 0l1.384 1.384c.293.293.293.768 0 1.061-.148.146-.339.22-.531.22z"/><path d="m15.75 12.5c-.414 0-.75-.336-.75-.75 0-1.517-1.233-2.75-2.75-2.75-.414 0-.75-.336-.75-.75s.336-.75.75-.75c2.343 0 4.25 1.907 4.25 4.25 0 .414-.336.75-.75.75z"/><path d="m13.25 24h-2.5c-.843 0-1.75-.64-1.75-2.044v-1.764c0-1.061-.452-2.035-1.209-2.605-2.185-1.645-3.196-4.351-2.639-7.062.545-2.656 2.694-4.813 5.347-5.368 2.11-.444 4.268.07 5.914 1.408 1.644 1.336 2.587 3.317 2.587 5.435 0 2.158-.975 4.161-2.675 5.498-.842.662-1.325 1.584-1.325 2.529v2.223c0 .965-.785 1.75-1.75 1.75zm-1.264-17.498c-.392 0-.787.041-1.182.123-2.076.434-3.757 2.122-4.184 4.201-.439 2.137.355 4.269 2.072 5.562 1.131.852 1.807 2.274 1.807 3.804v1.764c0 .091.012.544.25.544h2.5c.138 0 .25-.112.25-.25v-2.223c0-1.409.692-2.76 1.898-3.709 1.337-1.05 2.103-2.624 2.103-4.318 0-1.664-.742-3.221-2.034-4.271-.988-.802-2.213-1.227-3.48-1.227z"/>
</svg>
</div>
```